# How to add a C++ compiler flag to extconf.rb

Tags: c++, c, ruby

I'm writing a Ruby extension, for which I have a standard mkmf configuration script, but I need to add a special include flag (`--std=c++0x`) to all of the C++ compilation steps. I don't want it in the C compilation steps, 'cause it throws warnings. How should I do this?

```
require 'mkmf'
create_makefile('thing')
```

For instance, I tried `$CXXFLAGS << '-I..'`, but CXXFLAGS isn't defined, yet. If I use `$CXXFLAGS = '-I..'`, it's just overwritten later.

Comment: How did you solve this in the end?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.

```
$CXXFLAGS += " -std=c++11 "
```

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar situations handled by defining $(CXX) to be a combination of the compiler and the desired argument.

```
CXX=gcc --std=c++0x
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in extconf.rb. For one thing, would need quotes: `$CXX="gcc -std=c++0x"`; for another, only one dash for -std, according to compiler warnings. But either way, it doesn't seem to get passed to the Makefile -- in the Makefile, I just see `CXX = g++`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question but this is what worked for me:

```
$CXXFLAGS += '-I..'
```

Answer (score -2):

Just edit the Makefile generated by mkmf, that's the easiest way.

Open and rewrite Makefile after create_makefile(), in extconf.rb .

Editing RbConfig stuff is tough.